# How to prevent new line being sanitized in JSON?

Tags: php, curl

Basically, I would like to send textpost data to a foreign api but the text require new line and the new line that are being used by the server are \n.

The problem is every time I send a text data through curl, the post data will always be change from \n to \n rendering the new line unusable.

Here is my code:

```
$payload =  array('payload' => json_encode(array(
                                             'username' => 'Error-Bot',
                                             'text' => 'This contain a \n new line')));

$ch = curl_init($slackWebhooks);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);
        curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: \\n ? it's \n not /n.

Comment: Does this happen in curl or in Json ?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant \n, edited

Comment: @marged, yeah you are right, when I manually make the text the text are properly being sent.

Comment: So it is not a curl issue ;-) Change your question accordingly. But a newline inside JSON is not a good idea, you will have to escape it in a way the receiver supports (which by definition is `\\n`, so your library is doing everything the right way).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The replacement of `\n` is taking place in `json_encode`, not during curl.

Your string contains a "real" linebreak, which is not legal in JSON and thus needs to be modified. Because of this `\n` gets replaced by `\\n` which on the receivers end has to be treated accordingly.

But this should not be a problem because the `\\n` simply tells javascript (which is the basis for JSON) that the string contains a backslash (`\\` escapes the backslash) and a `n`. So the receiver can re-convert this into a linebreak.

If this does not work out you have to provide more details about the receiver / foreign api.